# weird array behavior with .push

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a scheduling script that grabs schedule data from a multidimensional array and pushes only the values from the original array that correspond to the current time to a second multidimensional array that contains only people currently working.

Here's a simple example of how the data is stored:

```
[["John Smith",0700,1700],["Peter Smith",0900,1600]]
```

Only in my data, the start time is stored in index 7 and end time is in index 8 of the internal array (not sure if I'm using the right terminology here).

My if statement is evaluating two values from the original schedule (start time and end time) that are located in an array called workingToday, seeing if the current time is between those values, and if it is it uses the push method to copy the corresponding array (containing the worker name, start/end times, etc) into a new array called workingNow.

Other than building the initial array workingToday from the schedule I pull from another site, I don't perform any modifications on this array. Every other function I perform is done on workingNow after that initial if statement that pulls the data from workingToday into workingNow.

The problem I'm having is that further down the line, when something modifies the workingNow array, it also modifies the original workingToday array which is screwing up some other features I'm trying to implement. I was under the impression that pushing the values into the new array doesn't link them to the old array, but I suppose this could be wrong.

Here's my code for the if statement:

```
var workingNow = [];
for (i = 0; i < workingToday.length; i++){
    //convert time strings to numbers to compare
    var startTime = parseInt(workingToday[i][7]);
    var endTime = parseInt(workingToday[i][8]);
    //compare start and end times with the current time and add those working to the new array
    if(startTime < parseInt(moment().format('hhmm')) && parseInt(moment().format('hhmm')) < endTime){
        workingNow.push(workingToday[i]);
    };
};
```

As an example of the problem I'm encountering, say I've pulled this data for workingToday (I've added another value like an employee ID to index 1:

```
[["John Smith",1234,0700,1700],["Peter Smith",4567,0900,1600],["June Smith",8901,1200,2200]]
```

And the current time is 1100. The output for workingNow should be:

```
[["John Smith",1234,0700,1700],["Peter Smith",4567,0900,1600]]
```

since June isn't working. Then, later I use the splice method to remove the employee ID to get this:

```
[["John Smith",0700,1700],["Peter Smith",0900,1600]]
```

The problem I'm encountering is that even though I performed this splice method on the workingNow array, the values from the original workingToday are also modified so that the employee ID is removed there as well. So workingToday ends up looking like this:

```
[["John Smith",0700,1700],["Peter Smith",0900,1600],["June Smith",8901,1200,2200]]
```

(where only June Smith still has her employee ID in the array) even though I did not perform these functions on the original array.

I hope I'm making some sense here. I'd just like to be able to push values from one array into a new array and then perform modifications to the new array without affecting the original data. If that is how the push function should work, then perhaps I've made a mistake somewhere else--I can't really figure out where that would be though since I really don't do anything else with the workingToday array so I don't know how it would be getting modified.

Comment: When you do `workingNow.push(workingToday[i]);` you're just pushing a reference to the inner array into `workingNow`, so your two arrays - `workingNow` and `workingToday` will reflect any changes made to the others. You'll need to clone `workingToday[i]` and push the result of that operation into `workingNow`.

Comment: To add to @AnthonyGrist 's answer - use `workingNow.push(workingToday[i].slice());` to create a copy of `workingToday` item.